# US States Drop Down List - need State Name Header to Show

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to display the state name as a header on the results page.  Here's where it gets tricky and maybe I'm going about this all wrong.

I am using the state abbreviation/id value to query users which use the ApplicationDbContext and the state value stored in that table is the abbr. only (not the name).   As you can see below in the controller block, I am trying a new query to my main db context to pull the state name and store it in a viewbag.

When you select a state and enter it all works like it should but the ViewBag.NameOfState displays this:

```
 SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[StateAbbr] AS [StateAbbr], [Extent1].[StateName] AS [StateName] FROM [dbo].[StateOrProvinces] AS [Extent1] WHERE ([Extent1].[StateAbbr] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[StateAbbr] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) 

    Controller:

     public ActionResult ShopsUS(string id)
            {            
                ApplicationDbContext ShopDB = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var stateList = ShopDB.Users.Where(s => s.State == id).OrderBy(s => s.City);

             //Second db query to get the state name for header display   
             if (stateList != null)
                {
                    CatalogDb db = new CatalogDb();
                    var _nameOfState = db.StateOrProvinces.Where(n => n.StateAbbr == id);
                    ViewBag.NameOfState = _nameOfState;
                }

                return View(stateList.ToList());

            }

    Controller Using LINQ instead:

            public ActionResult ShopsUS(string id)
            {            
                ApplicationDbContext ShopDB = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var stateList = ShopDB.Users.Where(s => s.State == id).OrderBy(s => s.City);

                if (stateList != null)
                {
                    CatalogDb db = new CatalogDb();
                    var name = from n in db.StateOrProvinces
                                       where n.StateAbbr == id
                                       select n.StateName;

                    ViewBag.NameOfState = name;
                }

                return View(stateList.ToList());

            }
```

The value is being passed as a string and matches the id passed in to the controller (id: "AL", "AK", whatever is selected.  Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you displaying the ViewBag object in your view?  You also have to keep in mind that your query is returning an OBJECT, not a single property of an object.  It should be:

```
 var _nameOfState = db.StateOrProvinces.Where(n => n.StateAbbr == id).State;
```

Where "State" is the column of the full state name.

Also, when retrieving a single record, you should use "Single", "SingleOrDefault", or "Find" (if the param is a primary key)
`var _nameOfState = db.StateOrProvinces.Single(n => n.StateAbbr == id).State`;